# Regex for removing leading zeros from neative float numbers

Tags: regex

guys.
I have a problem. My input strings looks like:

- 1-000000.02
- 1-000000.00
- 1+000025.48
- 1-000025.47
- 1-000000.00
- 1+000000.00
- 1+000025.46

And I want to extract normilize (remove plus sign, remove leading zeros, but exclude one zero before dot) float numbers like this:

- 0.02
- 0.00
- 25.48
- -25.47
- -0.00
- 0.00
- 25.46

I use next expression: 0*([0-9]+.?[0-9]+) (http://regexr.com/3dicv), it's works fine, but I can't catch minus sign ("25.47" instead "-25.47").
So if somebody point me to right way I will very grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: What about `1?[+-]0*([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)`?

Comment: Does [What is a non capturing group? (?:)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) give you any clues?

Comment: Will, I used similar variant - in this case we lost "-" in negative numbers.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your comment. I'm using noncapturing groups in my expressions. But the problem that when number is negative leading zeros placed INSIDE capturing group (-000012.34), and in this case leading zeros will catch too(

Comment: Can't you replace `.replace(/^1?([+-])0*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$/, "$1$2")`?

Comment: Wiktor, thanks. Unfortunately - no. I can't use replace, my final goal - extract number without language-specific tools. Rather, this is my last posibility - use post-proccessing function for "normalizing" any input number, but I want to skip this variant very strong.

Comment: You cannot use single regex match operation to match discontinuous texts. You have to use a replace or capture the different string parts to concatenate them later.

Comment: I was able to add an optional hyphen (`-?`) to the front of your regexr expression and match the minus signs.

Comment: Is there a reason for keeping `-` before `0.00` ? I'd more think of [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/fP9bE6/1) but useless if you can't use replace (:

Answer (score 2):

This works in [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/)

```
\d[+]?([-]?)0*(\d+\.\d+)
```

Replace:

```
$1$2
```

For these values:

```
1+000050.93
1-000025.47
1+000000.00
1-000000.00
1+000000.02
1-000000.02
1+100025.47
1-100025.48
```

It returns :

```
50.93
-25.47
0.00
-0.00
0.02
-0.02
100025.47
-100025.48
```

But I don't see why the trailing zero's are an issue when you would use it in C++.
This C++ seems to extract and parse it to a double just fine.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string teststring("1+000001.62");

    regex re("1([+-][0-9]+[.][0-9]{2})");
    smatch match;

    string resultstring = regex_replace(teststring, re, "$1" );
    double value = std::atof(resultstring.c_str());
    cout << value;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This regex requires anchors or it will might match what is not required

Comment: Luk, thanks for your example - it's a very good, but it produce TWO separate capturing group, not one. I agree with Wiktor from last comment in init post - this task is unsolveable with regex.

Comment: So the language you would be using it for can't handle multiple capture groups? A pity if that's the case.

Comment: Luk, of course, my language (C++, boost, Qt) allow to do any actions with regexs, but I want to have unificate method for proccessing input strings from different instruments, for execute this condition I need  to have one capturing group. So as we found out that my task is unsolveable, I will use post-proccessing function where will be placed replace() and all others.

Comment: You could use something like this 1([+-]\d+\.\d{2})  That only has 1 capture group. but it will contain the leading zero's. But would that really be a problem to cast to a number in c++ ?

Answer (score 1):

## Description

You just have to validate your string with a look ahead, then match the substrings you want removed while capturing the minus sign if it were there.

```regex
(?=^[0-9][+-][0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$)(?:[0-9]+(?:(-)|\+))0+(?!\.)
```

**Replace with:** `$1`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- validate your string is in the format integer plus or minus real with two decimal points
- replaces everything else that is not desirable, like the leading integer, and zeros before the decimal point, not including the zero directly before the decimal point.

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/mP4gH1/2

**Sample text**

```
1-000000.02
1-000000.00
1+000025.48
1-000025.47
1-000000.00
1+000000.00
1+000025.46
```

**After Replacement**

```
-0.02
-0.00
25.48
-25.47
-0.00
0.00
25.46
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [+-]                     any character of: '+', '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                             "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        -                      '-' character
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \+                       '+' character
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  0+                       '0' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```